# How can I read array from my web page cshtml in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, web

I'm building a Asp.Net application. I have this file

In `TimeDomain.cshtml` I want to display a chart, the data of this chart is on database. So this is the code of my controller:

```
public ActionResult TimeFrequency()
        {
            ArrayList arrayValue = new ArrayList();
            arrayValue.Add(0.5);
            arrayValue.Add(0.1);
            arrayValue.Add(0.5);
            arrayValue.Add(0.5);
            arrayValue.Add(0.3);
            arrayValue.Add(0.8);

            ViewBag.ArrayValue = arrayValue;
            return View();
        }
```

In the `TimeDomain.cshtml` I have this code to display the chart with random value:

```
var myConfig = {
                        type: 'bar',
                        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
                        plot: {
                            lineColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            lineWidth: "2px",
                            backgroundColor2: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            marker: {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                borderColor: "white",
                                shadow: false
                            }
                        },
                        plotarea: {
                            backgroundColor: "white"
                        },
                        series: [{
                            values: getRandomValue(),
                            lineColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            lineWidth: "2px",
                            alpha: 0.5,
                            borderWidth: "2px",
                            borderColor: "#C7C7C7",
                            borderTop: "2px solid #C7C7C7",
                            borderBottom: "0px",
                            backgroundColor1: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            backgroundColor2: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            marker: {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            }

                        }]
                    }
```

In this line code:

```
 values:getRandomValue(),
```

the method `getRandomValue` return an array of values. I want to remove this method and read the value from controller

```
 ViewBag.ArrayValue = arrayValue;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert c# array to js array like that

```
var jsArray= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.ArrayValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take `ViewBag.ArrayValue` in javascript variable as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var dataArray= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.ArrayValue));
</script>
```

Change your code like below in `myConfig` of chart configuration

```
 values:dataArray
```

Comment: I have this error, 'JSon' does not contain a definition 'Serialize'

Comment: Try with                                                                                                                  `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ArrayValue)`. Remove `Json.Serialize`